# Как добавить проект Unittest-ов в Visual Studio Code ( Asp.Net Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, юнит-тесты, visual-studio-code

Есть проект, назовём его testProject и есть проект Unittest нужно что бы проект  Unittest видел папку Models из проекта testProject, как это сделать?

Пробовал через reference 
(`dotnet add reference ..\testProject\testProject.csproj`)

в файле `Unittest.csproj` появилась запись

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\testProject\testProject.csproj" />
    <Content Include="UnitTest1.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

но проект не видит папку Models и нет доступа к моделям

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       List<Category> category = new List<Category>;
    }
```

и так же не видит using

```
using testProject.Models;
```

которые в проекте `testProject`

Как можно это настроить?

Код модели

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace testProject.Models
{
    public class Category : Entity
    {

        [Display(Name = "Название")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: код модели с юзингами покажите

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test

Comment: @tym32167 это я уже читал, но у меня уже есть 2 проекта. Мне нужно их сконектить. А, там описываться новый проект.

Comment: ну так сделайте как там описано, если оно у вас сработает, то смотрите разницу между теми проектами и вашими

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я перетащил проект Unittest в окно уже открытого проекта testProject. Иерархия папок получилась та же, но почему то он её не понял. Нужно было просто папку в которой находятся два проекта, открыть через добавить папку. И тогда всё работает.